# How does BytesIO.read() detect an end of file?

Tags: python, string, bytesio

I’m trying to understand how BytesIO works.

I’m trying to read a PostScript file from a PDF. When I convert the file to a string I read everything correctly except the end of it is gibberish.

```
dup 116 /t put
dup 117 /u put
dup 118 /v put
dup 119 /w put
dup 120 /x put
dup 121 /y put
dup 122 /z put
readonly def
currentdict end
currentfile eexec
Ÿ÷oc;Ñj≤Ñº¯∞Aw-ÂŒ=”%ÂWò)-{ŸrΩu˙ï)ØúÇﬂrˆAï…¬‹„E(ı@⁄˝{Îπ¥á∫ìQª˚|¸_ëR—Âª
ÿ–∆œ§ÎA≥≈ -T@Ê|˝q|VÅkπøJ%†qu8P¢¯wƒGx≥≈™€ÃÜ÷ÂQÊØ6K¸™“-çUå\Åß‘%°bù’"t-*x‘ıˆ”üœˇJë+
}Ïç3•{Z‡2é˘’z›¨T2s¿$ZıÃ—&{BËñJ◊{®•ﬂrÃó’ΩÕ·mî1lË(zÂNR¯rÈÚ^&%œ:(/Iãåﬂ∫Hímß!í4ù‹JﬂxIÚ7πbs,OíiˇOl7≥5R9Â¡˙ü≥zË(≤X*áRhï≥n√5áü≥&à£Âg«¸çﬁ\«c› ›µ∏9`EπΩÄ‚gú≤wÅÈ›T!…‹x»I‘ÒJz“àvÈ„*lÙcõo∆øÊÕsdm^ï%µµÇ=Ë∞∫ïüD+ã≥ùuˆ9πç#ïúö†π3µP«_]≤ÂÎ)õØËª≈w
¯à≈Í„™U™ˇAØ≠†8ú§  Hèé˘∑á·ÕuG–·:Dﬁá·Jàé˛(Ü¢ÛW≠¬ÛÕæÛÔ]£-0<.™gSBNlîZûOêLÔ”°é5^9¥√˛:ßK∫*|ÓF
ÇÑˇ{√â ⁄áÄ™÷E,ﬂû˚qº>Ωj0^óxÎñ≤Q≈˛'X√ÈÌÈÖâºi…;yZ…Pıt∏„¢>ˇ±ÿ‹pÁ1ÅSV∞}è«:¶¿ﬁ™aÛd0hƒ◊{<m’2wÌÃüñ˙ÜÖg5∆~Çñ»Ô
```

When I do `BytesIO.read()` in Python it somehow knows that there is gibberish and removes it.
My question is how does it know? Is there an end of file character that it looks for? If so what is it?

Comment: "Is there an end of file character that it looks for?" Yep. "If so, what is it?" Well, we computer scientists are a creative bunch, so we call it... [the end of file character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file).

Comment: No, there is no such thing as a end-of-file character in PDF.

Comment: And no, `BytesIO` does not do any end-of-file things. In any case, your question lacks any reproducability; you do not even give an example of the data produced by `BytesIO.read`

Comment: What makes you think it's gibberish and not binary data in the PDF?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Then how do you explain the text "If the size argument is negative, read until EOF is reached. Return an empty string at EOF." in `help(io.BytesIO.read)`?

Comment: I think the real question is how you know you have finished?  If a read of any size returns empty bytes then you are done seems to be all that is offered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, some systems do have an end-of-file character. **MS-DOS** used the `^Z` (`b'\x1a'`) in *text* files to signify the end of file. If the file was opened in binary mode, this wouldn't be the case. In UNIX, the `^D` (`b'\x04'`) (can be used on terminal to signify the end-of-file for text that is entered from terminal; however it is not something that is written to a file; there is no end marker.

Instead of any magic character, the EOF, or end-of-file, is *usually* just a condition. The operating system knows how big each file are, and keeps track on where each open file is being read. Now, if the read position on some file is at `1000` (0-based) and the file is `1000` bytes long, and you try to read more, the operating system will say `EOF` instead of giving you more bytes.

Now of course this again does not apply at all to `BytesIO` either, because it is not a file, but an emulation thereof. `BytesIO(data)` behaves like a readable file whose size would be `len(data)` and that would have the bytes of `data`; but there is no actual file anywhere; with `BytesIO` Python just emulates how an operating system would behave should it be a file like that. Thus the `.read()`, given no arguments there always returns all the data from current "file" position to the end of "file", that is, the splice `data[current_file_position:]`.